# Como selecionar determinado post no Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Gostaria de selecionar posts para adicionar uma class só para ele.

Por exemplo tenho linhas com 3 posts cada uma, e gostaria de selecionar o 3 post para adicionar uma divisão para a próxima linha.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou teria outra forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

A melhor maneira de se fazer isso, na minha opinião, é utilizando seletores do CSS3 por exemplo:

```
p:nth-child(n+3) { color:#f00; }
```

Assim você seleciona sempre o terceiro p de determinado elemento.

Comment: Desta forma funciona. Mais gostaria de saber se tem uma forma de selecionar pelo query do Wordpress mesmo. Pois dessa forma se não me engano não funciona em algumas versões de IE.

Answer (score 0):

Você consegue isso contando os posts dentro do loop e criando linhas de 3 posts:

```
<?php 
$i = 0;
if ( have_posts() ) {?>
   <div class="row"><?php //abre a primeira linha
        while ( have_posts() ) {
        $i++;
        if (($i > 3) & (($i % 3) === 1)){ //se for o primeiro de uma nova linha
        ?></div><div class="row"><?php //fecha a linha anterior e abre uma nova      
        }

        the_post(); 

        //
        // Conteúdo do post
        //

    }?></div><?php // end while fecha a última linha
} // end if
?>
```

E no css:

```
.row {border-bottom: 5px solid red;}
```

Esse código é só um esboço pra dar uma idéia... deve ser melhorado de acordo com o seu template.